# Gráfico de Barras no ggplo2, geom_bar()

Tags: r, ggplot2

Fiz este gráfico com `geom_bar()`, gostaria que as barras ficassem coladas na linha inferior, indicada pelas setas. Como poderia fazer?

Tem algum parâmetro da função `theme()` que pode resolver esse problema?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Por favor, [dê uma olhada neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/824/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-reproduz%c3%advel-em-r) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta adicionar `scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))` ao gráfico. Exemplo:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species)) + geom_bar() + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito obrigado! funcionou perfeitamente!